# How to add custom settings fields to general settings page in vBulletin 3.8 admin panel

Tags: settings, vbulletin

I'm new to vBulletin, so excuse me if I could not describe the what I want the best way.

I searched a lot about a tutorial or even a documentation describing how to add custom settings fields to general settings page in vBulletin admin panel but no way unlike the Wordpress which is much easier to get tutorials to.

[image: Adding additional fields to this view]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on Debug Mode will allow you to add new settings to the Admin CP.

To do so, edit your **includes/config.php**

- add `$config['Misc']['debug'] = true;` on a new line after `<?php`
- Go back to **Admin CP > Settings > Options**
  on that page you should see links for adding options.